# Generic Hash for unknown number's size

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

If I have an unknown dynamic size of options, that I want to do a java Hash function for them, is it correct to use the same Hash for all the possibilities?

i.e -

The input can be numbers [0-1000] and it can be [0-2^40]. 
I want the function to give me an output that will be uniquely as possible and that it will spread the inputs equally as possible. 
for example - `f(x) = x % 100` will spread the input equally as possible but I'm pretty sure it's not so efficient...

is the Hash (even a good one) will still be efficient for all the inputs?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

I have list of id's. I want to hash sets of id's (i.e - [1,3,5,16,22] or [2,23,43,44]) of that list, to a table of sets, to find out if the set of number is exists or not.

for example - I have a table of id's [0-70], and a table of sets that I used already. There are 2^70 possibilities of sets, and I don't want to create them all, so I create them on demand.

If I want to use the set [1,2,45,51] so I want to first check if this set exists (by hash for instance) in the "set" table, and if it doesn't, I want to add it.

The table of id's is dynamic and it can grow to 100, a thing that will change the number of sets to 2^100.

My purpose is to find the existence of a set in a quickest way.

(I also thought about representing the ids as a bits and if we want to find a set [1,2,5] we will search for 10011)

Comment: Can you create a more specific and precise example?

Comment: What do you mean by a hash function? A digest like SHA1 or a hash function complying with `Object.hashCode()`? What do you mean by "options"? How do you intend to hash an option?

Comment: @Zabuza is it clear now?

Comment: @RealSkeptic no.. a regular hash function that takes a number from a number range and give an output that should be smaller. hope the edit will make it clear.

Comment: You might want to read about [multiplicative hashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Multiplicative_hashing).

Comment: What do you mean by "a regular hash function"? What are you using it for? If you're not overriding `hashCode` then you intend to do something other than a hash table with it. What is the use case?

Comment: @RealSkeptic you were right... I edit it for you :)

Comment: OK. So why don't you keep the table of used set as a set of sets? A hash set will do nicely, and a set already has a `hashCode` function allowing it to be used in a `HashSet`. How are you keeping the table of sets right now?

Comment: right now it is implemented as ManyToMany table. it contains duplication and it's not efficient...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want the hash of an array of `long`? (primitive type `long` can handle number in a range from `-2^63` to `2^63`)

I suggest you to use:

```
int java.util.Arrays.hashCode(long a[])
```

This will give you an hash on `32 bit` that the simplest way to my sense.

according to your edit you seem to want an java.util.HashSet with just a custom hashcode on MyNumberImplem is exactly what you search , for this suggest you juste a best pratice about doing this : let your IDE work for you.

I just write this :

```
public class NumberContainer {
    private long[] data;

    public NumberContainer(long[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data.clone();
    }
}
```

i use the methode Generate HashCode and Equals (always write the 2 methods togegther!) the menu in eclipse is Source menu (on right click or on your Frame toolbar) :

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(data);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    NumberContainer other = (NumberContainer) obj;
    if (!Arrays.equals(data, other.data))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

java.util.HashSet is a Collection with optimization on the contains methods base on HashCode to optimzed more your effisciency you can do the same thing than java.lang.String and bufferize your hashcode result this will become your class :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NumberContainer {
    private final long[] data;

    public NumberContainer(long[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data.clone();
    }

    private Integer hashCode = null;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (hashCode == null) {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            hashCode = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(data);
        }
        return hashCode;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NumberContainer other = (NumberContainer) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(data, other.data))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this efficient equally for small and big range?

Comment: the more the array is big the more the computation will be long (O(n)) but i need some test for checking the repartiton

Comment: after some test on large set of object (sorry for my latency my computer didn't want to do it faster ) the hashset seems to have a uniform repartition this should corespond to your need